# Make gvim scroll to the center after opening a file with line numbers?

Tags: gvim

When I open a file with gvim with the following command line option,

`gvim file +5`

I would like the current line (the 5th line) be scrolled to the center of gVIM's window,
Is that possible?

```
--=--=----=--=----=--=----=--=--
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|  this line was selected    |
|                            |
--=--=----=--=----=--=----=--=--
```

By default, it wasn't centered

Comment: Are you referring to the same behavior that typing `zz` in normal mode would offer?

Comment: @Bernhard zz is not an editor command?

Comment: @Bernhard anyway, if this "zz" can be used once, it would solve my problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392424/how-can-i-open-vim-with-a-particular-line-number-at-the-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`gvim file +5 -c "normal zz"`

The `-c` option allows you to specify an editor command to run when starting vim. `zz`, as others have mentioned, centers the screen on the cursor line.

Answer (score 0):

Use an autocommand.

```
au VimEnter * normal zz
```

Comment: And if he does not want to do this by default?